measure of Haar
Let $(G,K)$ be a Gelfand pair.
Why, for a function $f$ $K$-binvariant with respect to a compact subgroup $K$ of a group $G$, do we have the following equality:
$$ f(xy) = \int_K f(xky) \, dk$$
A function $ f : G \to \mathbb{C} $ is $ K $-binvariant if for all $ k_1, k_2 \in K $ and $ x \in G $
$$ f(k_1 x k_2) = f(x). $$

Replacing $x$ with $xy^{-1}$, this is equivalent to saying that $K$-biinvariance implies right invariance with respect to conjugates of $K$. There is a counterexample with $|G| = 6$.

Thank you for your help, my question is it false?

MathJax note: MathJax does not obey \( \), so \(f\) comes out (f), but, perversely, does obey \\\\( \\\\) (although apparently not in comments: \\\\(f\\\\) shows up as \\(f\\) (not a typo!)).  See Having the MO Mathjax parser recognise \( \) is a regex away. I have edited accordingly.  (Also, the usual spelling is "biinvariant", three 'i's, or "bi-invariant", rather than "binvariant", two 'i's.)

@SeanEberhard, I assume that you have in mind $G = \mathrm S_3$ and $K$ an order-$2$ subgroup.  Is that a Gelfand pair?

@LSpice Yes. (Also, the phrase "Gelfand pair" was added after I made my comment.)
